# Loading ZeroClipboard or ZClip (copy to clipboard button) via JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flash

I am trying to create on-click 'copy to clipboard' functionality. But I need this feature along with other content to be loaded using Ajax.

Due to cross browser security issues, I've noticed a lot of plugins doing the same thing uses Flash to bypass this. I'm using (jQuery) ZeroClipboard or ZClip, it works fine if I load it normally on the page, but as soon as I try and load the plugin using JQuery's Ajax it doesn't seem to want to load the flash movie and hence the functionality doesn't work.

Has anyone successfully loaded similar functionality via Ajax? Or any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "load the plugin using jQuery's Ajax"?   ZeroClipboard is something you add to your page.  It's not data you load via Ajax.  I have a page here http://www.pixel99.com/smugcustom/slideshow/ were I load data using ajax (it happens to use YUI rather than jQuery) and then use javascript to create ZeroClipboard elements in the page to make that data copyable.

Comment: Thanks, it gave me the idea of doing it differently. Loaded the libraries first (not called the libraries in the ajaxed script) and like you said attached the elements to Zclip after the content has been loaded.

Comment: If you stick that as an answer, I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your request, here's this info as an answer.  What do you mean "load the plugin using jQuery's Ajax"? ZeroClipboard is something you add to your page. It's not data you load via Ajax. I have a page here pixel99.com/smugcustom/slideshow were I load data using ajax (it happens to use YUI rather than jQuery) and then use javascript to create ZeroClipboard elements in the page to make that data copyable.